# How to deal with the radius when applying Euler's formula to determine the roots of a number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to find $1^{1/3}$. I use Euler's formula $1^{1/3} = (re^{i\theta + 2\pi*k})^{1/3}$

Why are you able to directly this time calculate r? Is r implicitly defined as magnitude?

Comment: Why Euler's formula? Use $z=re^{i\theta}$ instead?

Comment: @Jack That is better.

Answer (score 2):

To find $1^{1/3}$, you want $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
z^3=1.
$$
Now writing $z=re^{i\theta}$, one has
$$
r^3e^{i3\theta}=1
$$ 
Taking the absolute value on both sides, and noting that $r>0$, you get $r=1$. For $\theta$, note that $$1=e^{2\pi i}$$ which implies that
$$
3\theta+2k\pi=2\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

in this formula, $r$and $\theta$ are both real numbers, and $r$ is nonnegative.

So you get
$$
r^{1/3} \left[ \cos \frac{\theta}{3} + i \sin \frac{\theta}{3} \right].
$$

**Post comment additions**

Let me add a little detail. The first problem is that $a^b$ has two different meanings.

1. We define $a^b$, for $a$ real and positive, using logarithms (it's $\exp{b \ln a}$), which are in turn defined by integrals, and $\exp$, which is defined as the inverse function of the natural log.
2. We define $z^b$, for $z$ complex and $b$ real, by a somewhat different rule.

The challenge is that when you now write $z^b$ and $z$ happens to be a complex number whose imaginary part is zero...you don't know which rule to use. To keep it clear, I'm going to use $pow(a, b)$ to refer to the thing described in item 1 above. Then we can describe #2 as follows:

Write $z = r (\cos t + i \sin t)$, where $r \ge 0$ is real, and so is $t$. Then 
$$
z^b = pow(r, b) (\cos s + i \sin s)
$$
where $s = (t + 2k\pi)b$ for any integer $k$.

This is a little odd, in the sense that there are many possible values for $s$, hence many possible powers of $z$. But what the heck: we have two square roots for nonnegative real numbers already, and just happen to be lucky that there's an easy way to consistently choose one of them (the nonnegative one) to call $\sqrt{x}$.

In the case where $z = 1$ and $b = \frac{1}{3}$, we end up with 
$$
1^{1/3} = pow(1, 1/3) (\cos s + i \sin s).
$$
Now $pow(1, 1/3) = 1$, so this simplifies to just 
$$
1^{1/3} = \cos s + i \sin s.
$$
where $s = t/3 + 2\pi k/3$, where $t$ is the "angle" for $z = 1$. That angle happens to be $0$, so $s$ is just "any multiple of $2\pi/3$.

Comment: I know, but for r, the original problem arises.

Comment: Nope -- computing cube roots of nonnegative reals is straightforward (e.g., by taking (real) logarithms). In the case of $r = 1$ (which is the situation you're in), $1^{1/3}$ is simply the positive-real cube root of $1$, which happens to be especially easy: it's $1$.

Comment: Yeah but r = 1, you can't just take the cube root. You need to do what you did originally. Apply euler's formula

Comment: @Goldname, no, you are simply taking a real cube root, as in applying function $\sqrt[3]{\ \ }\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Ennar You can't just do the same for "1" instead of going through all this trouble.

Comment: @Goldname, you are misunderstanding the formula. $r$ stands for radius, as in the absolute value of the complex number. Solutions to the equation $z^3 = re^{i\theta}$, geometrically speaking, form equilateral triangle in complex plain. Arguments of the three solutions are $\theta/3, \theta/3 + 2\pi/3, \theta + 4\pi/3$, but they all share the same _positive real_ radius, $\sqrt[3]r$, the _real_ cube root of the _real_ number $r$.

Comment: See post-comment additions.